# How to assign to an array in Pascal?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I'm getting an error I don't understand. I am trying to just assign a value to an element of an array in pascal.

```
function TestingThing() : Integer;
type
  IntegerArray  = array[0..$effffff] of Integer;
  PIntegerArray = ^IntegerArray;
var
  I: Integer;
  D: PIntegerArray;
begin
  for I := 0 to 5 do
    D[ I ] := I;
end;
```

This gives me an error on the line

`D[I] := I`

`Error: Incompatible types: got "LongInt" expected "IntegerArray"`

Comment: `D` is pointer, so you need to dereference it `D^[ I ] := I;`

Comment: Why are you using pointer types in this case?

Comment: @DelphiCoder Because `array[0..$effffff]` is a bogus data type. @Anthony does not want to allocate space for and use 251658239 integers, but only six.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt your comment doesn't make any sense. How are you supposed to know that?

Answer (score 4):

`D` is a pointer to an array of integers, it is not a pointer to a single integer, like you are expecting.

So, when you do `D[I]`, you are indexing into `D` and the resulting element is an array, and you can't assign a value to an array, hence the error.

You need to either:

- dereference `D` before you index into the array it points at:

  `D^[ I ] := I;`
- or, you need to change `D` to be a `PInteger` that points at the 1st `Integer` in the array, and then `D[I]` will work as expected.

Comment: And D must be initialized to point to some memory for the array.